# get Discussion setting in wordpress

Tags: users, comments

I am writing a shortcode for comments

i need to know if admin wants users to logged in for commenting

i need to know  this option `user must be registered and logged in` for commenting

is there any function like :

`get_admin_option('discussion','only_logged_in');`

or

`is_comments_public($postId);`

Answer (score 0):

this code may help you

```
$status = get_option('comment_registration');
// 1 : Yes , user must be registered and logged in for commenting
// 0 : No (default)
```

You can use the following code for the comment section

```
if (comments_open($postId)) {
    if (get_option('comment_registration') == 0 || is_user_logged_in() ){
      //render comments section
    }else{
        echo "You must login first";
    }
}else{
    echo "comments are closed";
}
```

also you can see other options in https://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference